# Removing newline at the end of a variable read from .txt file

Tags: python, variables, text-files, newline, python-3.4

### The problem:

All in all, I want to remove, take off, get rid off the extra blank line that is contained within a variable which is essentially a line which has been read from a .txt file

### In more detail:

So the scenario is this:
I have a program which takes data from two .txt files, and combines parts of the data from each file to make a new file with data from both

```
    search_registration = 'QM03 EZM'
    with open('List of Drivers Names and Registrations.txt', 'r') as search_file, open('carFilesTask1.txt', 'r') as search_av_speed_file, open('Addresses Names Registrations Speeds to Fine.txt', 'a') as fine_file:
        for line in search_file:
            if search_registration in line:
                fine_file.write(line)
        for line in search_av_speed_file:
            if search_registration in line:
                current_line = line.split(",")
                speed_of_car = current_line[2]
                print(speed_of_car)
                fine_file.write(speed_of_car)
```

In the second `for` loop, the program searches the .txt file which has the average speeds for the same numberplate registration as was searched for in the first `for` loop, and splits the line which has this registration using the commas within the text file:

> QM03 EZM,1.0,1118.5

The average speed is '1118.5', as it is the third split of the line.

However...
When writing the line with desired registration from the list shown below it seems to add a newline which I do not want

An example of this list is:

> CO31 RGK, Niall Davidson, YP3 2GP
>
> QM03 EZM, Timothy Rogers, RI8 4BX
>
> EX97 VXM, Pedro Keller, QX20 6PC

And an example of the output is

> IS13 PMR, Janet Bleacher, XG3 8KW
>
> 2236.9
>
> QM03 EZM, Timothy Rogers, RI8 4BX
>
> 1118.5

As you can see, the speeds of the car are different, one is travelling at `2236.9` and the other at `1118.5`, showing the string on the second line of each re-run of the program is the one taken from the second original file (the one with the speeds)

I just want to get rid of this blank line, not within the original file, but within the `line` variable once it has been read from the file

Please help! I've searched everywhere and have not found anything specific to this problem, Thanks in advance!

Comment: _line_ contains the new-line character in it (`\n`). Thus, before using _line_, you should strip it from _line_. Try adding this line:  `line = line.strip()`. Does it help?

Comment: Yes, yes it does - Thanks @Tal J. Levy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of writing it straight away to the file, how about first saving it in variables first and writing it at once.You can do it like this,

```
for line in search_file:
    if search_registration in line:
        str1 = line;
for line in search_av_speed_file:
    if search_registration in line:
         current_line = line.split(",")
         speed_of_car = current_line[2]
         print(speed_of_car)
         str2 = speed_of_car
fstr=" ".join(str1,str2) #further formatting can be done here,like strip() and you can print this to see the desired result
fine_file.write(fstr)
```

In this way it will be much easier to format the strings as you want.

Comment: Thanks @wolfsgang, this makes sense also, thanks for your advice on how to structure my code also :)

Answer (score 0):

Ockhius answer is of course right but to remove unwanted characters at the beginning and end of a string: [str.strip([chars])](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=strip#str.strip)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not the `\n` (new line character) that magically spawn in `line`.

It is the `write` function to write strings to file. Every call of the `write` starts a new line in the output file.

Maybe you should concatenate output string and write all to the file.

```
search_registration = 'QM03 EZM'
with open('List of Drivers Names and Registrations.txt', 'r') as search_file, open('carFilesTask1.txt', 'r') as search_av_speed_file, open('Addresses Names Registrations Speeds to Fine.txt', 'a') as fine_file:
    for line in search_file:
        if search_registration in line:
            first = line
    for line in search_av_speed_file:
        if search_registration in line:
            current_line = line.split(",")
            speed_of_car = current_line[2]
            print(speed_of_car)
            out_str = first + speed_of_car
            fine_file.write(out_str)
```

Comment: This makes complete sense, thanks @Ockhius for your help